# Python: how to remove a tag with certain Id in html and its content?

Tags: python, html

I want to remove a tag (with certain id) from a html page. For example:

```
<div id="id1" >
      "Contents here"
</div>

<div id="id2"> ...</div>
```

If I want to remove the first tag, but not the second one, then how do I do it?

Comment: I have just installed BeautifulSoup, and now be able to find the tag, but not remove it. I can't find the id option to remove, and if I remove the div tag, not only the first but the second tag is removed.

Comment: Does not make sense what you are asking. Of course you can find div#id1 using BeautifulSoup and apply the extract() method to the found node. If you want something different: tell us but don't let us guess.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to Python. But i don't think the extract() method has an 'id' parameter to specify? In the document: [link](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) i_tag = soup.i.extract() removes all <i> tag.

Comment: Dude, read your BeautilfulSoup documentation. It is full of examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [**`BeautifulSoup`**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
In [32]: from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

In [33]: doc = '''<div id="id1" >
      "Contents here"
</div>
<div id="id2"> ...</div>'''

In [34]: soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)

In [35]: id1 = soup.find('div', id='id1')

In [36]: print soup
<div id="id1">
      "Contents here"
</div>
<div id="id2"> ...</div>

In [37]: id1.extract()
Out[37]: 
<div id="id1">
      "Contents here"
</div>

In [38]: print soup

<div id="id2"> ...</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Johnsyweb,that is what I was finding. Sorry for asking such a question, but I'm still very happy now that I've got the answer!

Comment: And now I'm using bs4, so the import command is "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup"